# Spring Maven Webapp Error with Tomcat Server 7

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, web-applications

I am new to maven and the spring framework. I had gathered all the dependencies and the pom builds successfully, however when I run it on the server I get the 404 screen.  I have no errors in the project, but when I run the new maven project on the Tomcat 7, I get the error below.  The tomcat server does not pick up the index welcome screen.  I have been attempting this for a month and a half now, any help would be much appreciated.  I have a feeling it is a dependency issue but I do not know enough to know what the problem is with it.

The error I get:

```
Jan 21, 2016 11:24:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.att.lpp.discovery.core.hardware.DiscoveryHardwareImpl] for bean with name 'discoveryHardware' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/discovery/core.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.att.lpp.discovery.core.hardware.DiscoveryHardwareImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1281)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1350)
    at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5591)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.att.lpp.discovery.core.hardware.DiscoveryHardwareImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1856)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1705)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1273)

INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 21, 2016 11:24:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fw.restClient': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.Client org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.create()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/client/ClientException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:589)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:951)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5077)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5591)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.Client org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.create()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/client/ClientException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:578)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/client/ClientException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.createWithValues(JAXRSClientFactoryBean.java:304)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.create(JAXRSClientFactoryBean.java:262)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.client.ClientException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1856)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1705)
```

POM dependencies and plugins File:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--  3.2.6.RELEASE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jetty-continuation</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jetty-io</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jetty-security</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.30</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.att.lpp.fw</groupId>
            <artifactId>fw-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/fw.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2-Final</version>
        </dependency> -->



<!--        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>3.5.2-Final</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
          <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>config</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlRoot>${basedir}/src/main/config</wsdlRoot>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.wsdl</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-WAR-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/generated/xsd</sourceRoot>
                            <xsdOptions>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/config/xsd/dao/DBAccessDataV1.xsd</xsd>
                                </xsdOption>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/config/xsd/ConfigurationDataV1.xsd</xsd>
                                </xsdOption>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/config/xsd/service-configuration-notification.xsd</xsd>
                                </xsdOption>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/config/xsd/NetworkAuthenticationDataV1.xsd</xsd>
                                </xsdOption>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/config/xsd/SnmpAuthenticationDataV1.xsd</xsd>
                                </xsdOption>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/config/xsd/ietf-inet-types.xsd</xsd>
                                </xsdOption>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/config/xsd/ari/DownloadNotificationData.xsd</xsd>
                                </xsdOption>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/config/xsd/ari/AriRequestResponse.xsd</xsd>
                                </xsdOption>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/config/xsd/ari/RunCommandNotificationData.xsd</xsd>
                                </xsdOption>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/config/xsd/ari/BulkPingNotificationData.xsd</xsd>
                                </xsdOption>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/config/xsd/ari/SnmpPollingNotificationData.xsd</xsd>
                                </xsdOption>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/config/xsd/ari/AriRequestData.xsd</xsd>
                                </xsdOption>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/config/xsd/rdb/RoutingDataV1.xsd</xsd>
                                </xsdOption>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/config/xsd/rdb/bgp/BgpMonitorDataV1.xsd</xsd>
                                </xsdOption>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/config/xsd/SystemAuthenticationDataV1.xsd</xsd>
                                </xsdOption>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/config/xsd/ConfigletDataV1.xsd</xsd>
                                </xsdOption>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/config/xsd/SdnControllerResponse.xsd</xsd>
                                </xsdOption>

                            </xsdOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and the web.xml is:

```
<display-name>configuration</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>com.att.lpp.fw.util.WhichContextProfile</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <!--  to enable multiple webapps in one tomcat -->
    <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/lppsdn-configuration.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener> 

<filter>
    <filter-name>UUIDFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UUIDFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/mvc/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/tasks/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <description>CXF WS servlet</description>
    <display-name>ws</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ws</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config-location</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/ws.xml</param-value>    
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <description>CXF REST Servlet</description>
    <display-name>rest</display-name>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config-location</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/rest.xml</param-value>    
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <description>Spring MVC Servlet</description>
    <display-name>mvc</display-name>
    <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/config/mvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <description>Spring Tasks Servlet</description>
    <display-name>tasks</display-name>
    <servlet-name>tasks</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/config/tasks.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>4</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ws</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mvc/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>tasks</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/tasks/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Fallout Management</web-resource-name>
        <description>Fallout Management security model</description>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/BMTFalloutToolConfigSearch</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/BMTFalloutToolConfigSearch.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/BMTFalloutToolConfigSearch.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/SearchBMTConfigletResults</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/SearchBMTConfigletResults.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/SearchBMTConfigletResults.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/BMTConfigletAction</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/BMTConfigletAction.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/BMTConfigletAction.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Fallout Management</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>CLI Translation</web-resource-name>
        <description>CLI Translation security model</description>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/CLIToolConfigSearch</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/CLIToolConfigSearch.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/CLIToolConfigSearch.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/SearchConfigletResults</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/SearchConfigletResults.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/SearchConfigletResults.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/translateCLIConfiglet</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/translateCLIConfiglet.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/translateCLIConfiglet.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/downloadAsFile</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/downloadAsFile.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/configuration/downloadAsFile.html</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>CLI Translation</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/mvc/fw/session/index</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/mvc/fw/error/index</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <description>Fallout Management</description>
    <role-name>Fallout Management</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-role>
    <description>CLI Translation</description>
    <role-name>CLI Translation</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Comment: You have: 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.att.lpp.fw</groupId>
            <artifactId>fw-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/fw.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

Is that jar actually there?

[sorry, no idea how to get the formatting here - if at all]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, yes, I have the FW jar in the specified path.

Answer (score 0):

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.att.lpp.discovery.core.hardware.DiscoveryHardwareImpl] for bean with name 'discoveryHardware' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/discovery/core.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.att.lpp.discovery.core.hardware.DiscoveryHardwareImpl
```

Your application can't find the class com.att.lpp.discovery.core.hardware.DiscoveryHardwareImpl, which i would expect to be in fw.jar.

You should check, if your tomcat is able, to find the referenced jar.

I would recommend, to add it to your tomcat-libs folder. If you can't add it to the libs folder, you need to add it in setenv.bat|sh to the CLASSPATH variable.